# How to change the catcode in a macro

Tags: macros, catcodes

I want to change the catcode in a macro, but it seems it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

```
\def\A{\catcode`\|=0 |bf{test}}
```

`|bf{test}` would not work as expect.

Comment: Li: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `|` was already read as part of the argument of `\def\A` and therefore has its catcode already before the included `\catcode` is executed.

You need to move the catcode change out of the macro:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`\|=0 
\gdef\A{|bf{test}} 
\endgroup
```

There are also other ways to do it: eTeX privides `\scantokens` which re-read its content so that the catcodes are reapplied and there is a trick to do it using `\lowercase`.

Note that in this example makes actually **no difference** if `\` or `|` is used. It would if you also change the catcode of `\` to something else. If you tell us more about your exact application more specific answers can be given.

Also note that your code example would make the catcode change active for the rest of the group `\A` is used in, which is most likely not what you intend.

Comment: Thank you. I know in general, I need to use this code out of a macro. But I wish I can write a macro, which read the stream begin with \\ (such as \test), then stores test (without \\) in somewhere. So, if I use

\begingroup
\catcode`\|=0
\catcode`\\=12
|@tfor|B:=\test|input|do{\if \|B |relax |else do something|fi}

Comment: @Kuang-Li Huang: You can convert a macro like `\test` read be macro as argument `#1` into `test using `\expandafter\@gobble\string#1`. Note that `\string` returns the following token (e.g. a macro) as its string representation, e.g. the macro `\test` as string "\test". The `\@gobble` then removes the `\\ `. The `\expandafter` is required to expand `\string` before `\@gobble`. Alternatively you can change the `\escapechar` variable which tells `\string` which character to place for the `\\ `.