# Define a custom command to wrap easylist

Tags: lists, itemize

I've installed the `easylist` package and am using it just fine. I've tried to create a  custom command to shorten my typing as I've done before with the regular `\begin{itemize}`.

My regular one that works is:

```
\newcommand{\itml}[1]{\begin{itemize} #1 \end{itemize}}
```

I use like this:

```
\itml{
    \item first item
    \item second item
}
```

The one that does **not** work:

```
\newcommand{\el}[1]{\begin{easylist}[itemize] #1 \end{easylist}}
```

When used as:

```
\el{
    # first item
    ## second item
}
```

I get the following error:

```
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode.
<argument>  ##
           first item #### Second item
l.44 }
```

What **actually does work** is:

```
\newcommand{\bel}{\begin{easylist}[itemize]}
\newcommand{\eel}{\end{easylist}}
```

When used as:

```
\bel
    # first item
    ## second item
\eel
```

Basically, I **don't** want to type the closing tag?

**UPDATE**: I have all of my custom commands in a separate file like so:

```
% commands.tex file
\newcommand{\avgE}{\bar{E}}

...

\newcommand{\bel}{\begin{easylist}[itemize]}
\newcommand{\eel}{\end{easylist}}
\newcommand{\el@aux}[1]{\begin{easylist}[itemize] #1 \end{easylist}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\el}{\begingroup\Activate\el@aux}
\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\bel #1 \eel}
\newcommand{\itml}[1]{\begin{itemize} #1 \end{itemize}}
```

And in my regular files, I say:

```
% regular latex file
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
...
\input{../src/commands.tex}
....
```

When trying it in my regular file I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.25 ...list}[itemize] #1 \end{easylist}\endgroup}
```

Does that mean I have to declare these custom commands in each "regular" file and cant put it in just one place for all files?

Comment: So you've found a workaround using an _environment_ type definition. Is your question that you want the _macro_ type solution to work as well?

Comment: Not sure what the difference is between them. Basically what I want is to **not** type a closing tag

Comment: When you have a macro-form of something, the argument is read at the current catcodes. So, when passing the argument to be used within an environment (similar to your `\el{..}` definition), the modification of catcodes by `easylist` no longer has an effect. Within the environment-form, no argument is gobbled and therefore the output works...

Comment: I see. So due to the way `easylist` works, I'd have to go with `\bel` solution as opposed to the `\el` solution? If so, you can answer the question and I'll accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to get what you want - locally updating the category code of `#` before reading the macro argument. [`easylist`](http://ctan.org/pkg/easylist) provides this functionality through `\Activate` (and a companion `\Deactivate`) that updates the category code of the required "item character":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sharp]{easylist}% http://ctan.org/pkg/easylist

% Environment-style definitions
\newcommand{\bel}{\begin{easylist}[itemize]}
\newcommand{\eel}{\end{easylist}}

% Macro-style definitions
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\el@aux}[1]{\begin{easylist}[itemize] #1 \end{easylist}\endgroup}
\newcommand{\el}{\begingroup\Activate\el@aux}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}

\el{
  # first item
  ## second item
}

\bel
  # first item
  ## second item
\eel
\end{document}
```

Local updating is ensured using a `\begingroup`...`\endgroup` clause (and therefore there is technically no need for a "closing" `\Deactivate`). `\el` actually only starts the process, while `\el@aux` is the actual macro that gobbles the argument to be passed to `easylist`.

Some references, for relevance:

- [Changing the catcode of _ in one command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33465/5764)
- [How to change the catcode in a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12638/5764)

Comment: Hey thanks for the update! I've updated my question with some additional error output. Any further help would be great!

Comment: @Diego: Since I'm using `@` in the definition of `\el@aux`, you need to use `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother`. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://goo.gl/HYwLd)