# Modify catcode in the preamble or in the \AtBeginDocument?

Tags: catcodes, active-characters

I want to modify the catcode of comma, with the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode`\,=\active
  \protected\def,{...}%
}
\begin{document}
a,b,c $a,b,c$.
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.6 \begin{document}
```

But with the following code, I get correct result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begingroup
  \catcode`\,=\active
  \protected\gdef,{...}%
\endgroup
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode`\,=\active
}
\begin{document}
a,b,c $a,b,c$.
\end{document}
```

I'm wondering what are the differences between these two ways. Why the first way causes problem?

**Edit**: Althougn David Carlisle give another related question, but I think this question maybe not the same as that question, since **both** examples contains

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode`\,=\active
}
```

I could not understand why only one example causes problem.

Comment: As explained in the linked answer this is the standard issue that catcode changes (like `\verb` to not apply to tokens, so do not work in the argument of another command)

Comment: Also similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201348/21930

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But I put `\catcode`\,=\active` inside `\AtBeginDocument` in **both** of the examples. I think it is not the same as your linked answer.

Comment: @Z.H. You need ``\catcode`\,=active`` _outside_ of `\AtBeginDocument` as well: the tokenization needs to be correct.

Comment: @Z.H. it is the same (and independent of anything specific about `\AtBeginDocument` I'm not sure what difference you see?

Comment: @JosephWright I am still confused, you means the catcode change doesn't reset after the group?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The linked question doesn't explain how to solve the issue: either this question should be reopened with an answer that does, or the linked one needs editing.

Comment: @JosephWright hmm perhaps this is a better dup http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12638/how-to-change-catcode-in-a-macro?rq=1  (or we could put an answer here, but it's such a FAQ it must be a dup of something:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh I understand it now. In fact, the statement *you could not change catcodes inside a command* in the linked question is wrong, The correct statement is *you could not change catcodes and redefine the active character inside the same command*.

Comment: @Z.H. it isn't the definition that you can not do it is that the catcode change does not affect the tokens in the argument `\mbox{\catcode\`,=13 zzzz , zzzz}` it is a normal, non-active `,` between the `zzz` whatever that code is doing, definition or use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any way to make TeX do it anyway? Or would it involve a `\special` and a "fake" version of TeX with different handling of `\def`?

Comment: @1010011010 why? why not just use the standard tex syntax `\catcode\`,=13\mbox{ zzzz , zzzz}` obviously if you use some unspecified non-tex program it could do whatever you specify, but it would have to be very different from TeX so the question of making some Tex syntax work on that new system may not make sense at all.

Comment: @1010011010 You may use `\scantokens` command.

Comment: It's not a good idea to make the comma active, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the argument of `\AtBeginDocument`, the comma is *not* active. The comma becomes active, when the argument with the category code setting is *executed* later in `\begin{document}`. Also keep in mind, that the category codes gets assigned during the tokenization. When an argument is read, the bytes of the input are tokenized with the current category code regime. When the argument is executed, the category change of the comma will affect later tokenizations, but not the tokens of the remainder of the argument.

### Lowercase tilde trick

The typical pattern is to make use of the tilde character, because it is active in LaTeX by default. Then `\lowercase` is used to convert the tilde to the comma. The category code does not change in this process and the result is an active comma. A group prevents a permanent setting of the lowercase setting for the tilde.

```
\documentclass{article}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode`\,=\active
  \begingroup
    \lccode`\~=`\, %
  \lowercase{\endgroup
    \protected\def~%
  }{...}%
}
\begin{document}
a,b,c $a,b,c$.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Changing the category code for the whole statement

Another pattern is to change the category code for the whole statement including the argument. First the original category code of the comma is saved, e.g. via a resetting macro (`\ResetCommaCatcode`).
Then the category code of the comma is changed. Now `\AtBeginDocument` is called, the argument now contains an active comma token (in `\protected\def,`). Afterwards the category code of the comma is reset to the previous value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\ResetCommaCatcode{%
  \catcode`\noexpand\,=\the\catcode`\,\relax
}
\catcode`\,=\active
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \catcode`\,=\active
  \protected\def,{...}%
}
\ResetCommaCatcode

\begin{document}
a,b,c $a,b,c$.
\end{document}
```